# Understanding proxy settings in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, networking

I'm behind a university proxy and I'm very confused about Ubuntu's proxy settings and I'd love if someone can clarify it for me.

If I look inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf` it has my custom set proxy as

```
Acquire::http{Proxy "http://user:pass@proxy:port";};
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:pass@proxy:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:pass@proxy:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:pass@proxy:port/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://user:pass@proxy:port/";
```

Inside `/etc/environment` I have

```
http_proxy="http://proxy:port/"
https_proxy="https://proxy:port/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://proxy:port/"
socks_proxy="socks://proxy:port/"
```

But if I do this `echo $http_proxy` then I get

```
http://differentproxy:differentport
```

I don't get it from where it's 'echo'ing. Any clarification? I know I can export the $http_proxy variable to the correct proxy but I just want to understand what all files/settings Ubuntu uses for proxies.

Comment: Do you run `echo $http_proxy` from inside your desktop environment or in a virtual terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1)? This environment variable may be overridden by the DE - e.g. by values in the Proxy Settings in the System Settings.

Comment: I ran it from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Proxy settings are not the most friendly things in the world.  The attempts at standardising or creating global settings are not particularly successful.

Global configuration files (Such as /etc/environment) are not read by every application or every time they start, and are specific to Linux distributions.

Applications can use DE (Eg Gnome or KDE) environment settings.

User preferences, eg settings from the shell environment may (and should) override host or system global settings.

The order of priority between different configuration sources are frustratingly difficult to manage, eg System global configuration files, Desktop environment settings, and login script settings.

Application specific settings may override environment settings.

Changing "global" settings often require a restart of the application, sometimes even of the host, so it is more convenient to use the application specific settings in each application.

The end result is that the settings are not particularly dynamic.

In this case the setting for APT and /etc/environment most likely came from a setting you specified during installation.

The values seen in the terminal is quite likely being overridden in your login script or shell profile file, possibly in the users' Gnome global preferences.

Comment: For what it's worth, I developed ProxyManager (https://github.com/Tahaan/proxymanager) in an attempt at adressing these issues